# How to dynamically resize an iframe in Fancybox 2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox 2.0. I open content in an iframe. How can I dynamically resize
the popup window when the content in the iframe changes?

I google for hours but all links is either for older version (1.3) or dead ends.

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

I used the before show option to resize it:

```
 beforeShow: function(){
    this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').width();
    this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
 }
```

To get this to run from within frame, you need to fire the parent.$.fancybox.update() from the child page, which should resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the iframe width and height as per the content width and hight by use this option autoSize is true.
If autoSize is true, then sets both autoHeight and autoWidth to true. This means for 'inline', 'ajax' and 'html' type content width and height is auto determined.

```
$.fancybox.open({
padding : 0,
href:'http://www.gamespot.com',
type: 'iframe',
autoSize: true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```
$.fancybox({
  width:600,
  height:300,
  autoResize:false
});
```